Problems with xesmf import after offline migration conda environment
After migrating my conda environment offline(using conda pack), on the new platform, I get an error importing xesmf:
Traceback (most recent call last).
File "/home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/nc2p/lib/python3.11/site-packages/esmpy/interface/loadESMF.py", line 144, in
_ESMF = ct.CDLL(os.path.join(libsdir,'libesmf_fullylinked.so'),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/nc2p/lib/python3.11/ctypes/init.py", line 376, in init
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/esmf_1677849384616/h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold placeh/lib/libesmf_fullylinked.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last).
File "/home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/nc2p/lib/python3.11/site-packages/esmpy/interface/loadESMF.py", line 144, in
_ESMF = ct.CDLL(os.path.join(libsdir,'libesmf_fullylinked.so'),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/nc2p/lib/python3.11/ctypes/init.py", line 376, in init
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/esmf_1677849384616/h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold placeh/lib/libesmf_fullylinked.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I know it is a problem with the OS path after migrating the environment, so how do I change the LINK path? I have successfully deployed ESMF on the new platform.
My libesmf_fullylinked.so is in /home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/nc2p/lib/libesmf_fullylinked.so in python and /home/xxx/xx/esmf-8.6.0/lib/libO/Linux.intel.64.mpiuni.default in ESMF

